# How can i let my PWA running on iOS 14 use browser initiated session?

Tags: ios, safari, progressive-web-apps, session-cookies, ios14

I have a PWA application running on iOS 14.2.

In this app, I have a simple login flow that triggers to open an in-app Safari browser to display a simple login form and then successfully redirects to my PWA home page.

But it seems not to get session information from this browser.

In Android and Chrome browser, everything is running as expected and using this newly initiated session, i can make cross origin requests with no problem.

Comment: what do you mean in app browser? Why would you need to open another browser to authenticate when you already in the browser, even from a home screen app.

Comment: Hi @ChrisLove when you redirect to a url using window.location in pwa, it simply opens a safari browser control inside pwa. That’s why i called it as in-app browser.